# Loading a PNG at runtime is creating a different height than the PNG loaded with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, background, png

I've never seen this before. If I set the background of a canvas like this:

```
<Canvas.Background>
    <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Combined Victorian.png"  Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" />
</Canvas.Background>
```

It looks like this at runtime:

[image]

Great! Just what I want. But later, on a button press, I'm switching between 2 images for the Canvas background. And when I load the exact same image like this:

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\Combined Victorian.png", UriKind.Relative));
MainCanvas.Background = brush;
```

It's squished and looks like this:

[image]

How might I solve this?

Comment: Did you try disabling `BitmapCache` option with `BitmapCache.None`

Comment: No. Where would I do that? Before or after the load?

Comment: Tried doing using this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456183/canvas-with-bitmapcache-render-after-removing-child No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first piece of markup sets Stretch="None" on the imagebrush.

Your code does not.

This is the difference.

Imagebrush inherits from tilebrush and you can see the stretch property on that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.tilebrush.stretch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_TileBrush_Stretch

You should probably be setting stretch to uniform if you want to retain aspect ration when the user resizes the window. Like when they start it maximised.

Comment: I never found a way to set imagebrush load to clip. Do you know how to do that? Otherwise, my solution, below, worked.

Comment: Viewbox allows you to pick which part of the bitmap to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewbox?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem: I cut the image so that it was the exact same size as the canvas that it was going into. What's happening is that loading a PNG from disk into a Canvas will stretch the image to fit the destination rect. There doesn't appear to be anyway to change this so it will just crop or 'not stretch' like doing it via XAML. If there is a way to specify 'no stretch', I haven't found it.